# Make LINQ extension methods apply to my class

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I have a Repository class, which as a method `FromStore<TEntity>` as below:

```
IQueryable<TEntity> FromStore<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
```

Using this I can do things like:

```
MyRepository.FromStore<DatabaseModel>().SingleOrDefault(dm => dm.Id = Id);
```

Now, i'm thinking it's silly to make users of the class call `FromStore` when I could provide the SingleOrDefault method directly (you'd just have to specify the generic type parameter rather than it being inferred as is normally the case).

So, I wrote a method as below:

```
public TEntity SingleOrDefault<TEntity>(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter) where TEntity : class
{
    return FromStore<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
}
```

Great! Now I can do this:

```
MyRepository.SingleOrDefault<DatabaseModel>(dm => dm.Id = Id);
```

However, I want to do the same for all the linq extension methods.
The only way I can think to do it currently is to create similar wrapper methods on my class for every single linq method.

This seems silly, surely there's a better way?

I was thinking could I somehow have my `Repository` class inherit the class that the linq extension methods extend, but they extend `IQueriable<T>`. My class doesn't implement that, because there's not just one `T` in the repository.

---

Can I get the linq extension methods to apply to my class somehow, even though I can't implement `IQueryable<T>` for a specific `T`?

Comment: To further complicate things the repository actually implements `IRepository`, which is what users of the API will see. So I think the extension methods would have to apply there (somehow??). If there's a solution without interfaces, but not with I'd be interested though.

Comment: I don't think you can do this, unless there's some way using `dynamic`. Any solution is likely to be messier than requiring your clients to call `FromStore`.

Comment: Thought that might be the case. If only I could implement `IQuerable<>` (no `T` specified)! I'll wait to see if anyone has any other ideas though.

Comment: If you knew all the `TEntities` you were likely to ever need, you could explicitly implement `IQueryable<TEntity>` for each concrete class. However, you still wouldn't be able to use `Linq` extension methods without explicitly casting your repository first, which defeats the purpose somewhat.

Comment: I'm trying really hard to envision a *non-generic* class having a *generic* method `Something<T>` without declaring the method itself... I can't :(

Comment: @AakashM: It would be like auto-casting to `IQuerable<T>` by using `FromStore<T>` when trying to use the extension method. Since it's not in C#/.net what I'm asking for probably doesn't make sense!

Comment: @AakashM: My thinking is along the lines of: I have a non-generic class that contains a generic method (`FromStore<T>`) to get a generic interface (`IQueryable<T>`). That generic interface has extension methods. I want to use those extension methods on my non-generic class by somehow using my generic method to create what the extension methods operate on / extend.

Comment: Is it then that you need to go down the route of being a LINQ Provider yourself?? speculating wildly here

Answer (score 0):

You could implement it as an extension method for your repository interface.

```
public static class RepositoryExtensions
{
    public static TEntity SingleOrDefault<TEntity>(
        this IRepository repository,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter
    )
    {
        return repository.FromStore<TEntity>().SingleOrDefault(filter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Possibly I've confused things by mentioning the interfaces. I'd like to know if I can avoid having to write something like the above for every linq extension method.

Comment: I suppose in order to do that you would need to write your own linq provider. That would require [implementing a Query Provider](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattwar/archive/2007/07/30/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i.aspx).

Comment: Hmm, ok. I can really get my head around what that would look like though, while being able to automatically be able to use the extension methods.

Comment: `IQueryable(T)` has its own separate extension methods in [`Queryable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx). The underlying expression tree (`IQueryable.Expression`) gets built with the method calls (`Where`, `GroupBy`, `OrderBy`, `Select`, etc) and their arguments which you can use to shape your data.

Comment: I understand how query providers work (at a basic level) but as I understand it I'd still end up with a repository (that is now a query provider) that has a create query method. To me that seems the same as my fromstore method now. There must be something I'm missing.

Comment: Well the `Expression` that is generated would be used on the `FromStore<T>()`. You're essentially using the query provider to bridge your repository to understand linq.

Comment: Sorry I must be missing something. I can already use linq methods with the fromstore result (since that is a queriable), so the repository understands linq. I guess I'm still not getting something. If you could maybe add classes with method signatures or something to your answer that might help. Sorry for all the questions!